# What is best experience to use date among java, mysql, javascript?

Tags: java, database, datetime

Most said UTC date should be used instead of local time in database.

I have a table

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Then I have a rest service to search users created between startedDate and endDate like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/client/rest/user?service=describe-users&startDate=2015-11-02T11:11:11&endDate=2015-11-03T11:11:11
```

Then I have the following questions to make a best solution:

1) the date saved in database has Timezone information, correct? It could be converted to UTC time?

2) Should I pass the UTC date parameter or local date parameter to the RESTful request?  Probably the answer is to convert time to UTC in javascript and then pass UTC date parameter, then select the users created between two UTC time.

3) How to use SQL to select UTC time between two dates? When I execute the following sql, it uses the local time to compare.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-02 11:11:11' AND '2015-11-02 11:11:11';
```